# Additional tags layer on camera's window (wp8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, camera, windows-phone

I'm working with camera on wp8. Now I want to achieve effect like in Nokia City Lens app. I want to add additional layer with POI tags on real time working camera's window. Have you any tips how to work with it? It's any library or something to draw tags on PhotoCamera's window? I totally don't know how to start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a `<Canvas>` with `<VideoBrush>` then you can add as many layers as you like.  For example:

```XAML
<!-- This will draw a Red Rectangle @ 50, 50 over the camera output -->
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Canvas x:Name="cam_canvas" Width="480" Height="480" Margin="-12,0">                
        <Canvas.Background>
            <VideoBrush x:Name="cam_video_brush" Stretch="None">
                <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform Rotation="90" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
                </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
            </VideoBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>

        <!-- draw rect -->
        <Rectangle Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red"></Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

---

Pay attention to Canvas.Top (Y position), Canvas.Left (X Position), Canvas.ZIndex (Layer number above the background video brush)